# Nativescript | Firebase notification not working

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

I'm having a problem using firebase in my Nativescript application, when I'm using android its working great but not working with IOS. the problem is on message sending.
I'm using the push-plugin in the client side

This is the register part in the IOS client side using pushPlugin

```
const iosSettings:any = {
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
        alert: true,
        interactiveSettings: {
            actions: [{
                identifier: 'READ_IDENTIFIER',
                title: 'Read',
                activationMode: "foreground",
                destructive: false,
                authenticationRequired: true
            }, {
                identifier: 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER',
                title: 'Cancel',
                activationMode: "foreground",
                destructive: true,
                authenticationRequired: true
            }],
            categories: [{
                identifier: 'READ_CATEGORY',
                actionsForDefaultContext: ['READ_IDENTIFIER', 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER'],
                actionsForMinimalContext: ['READ_IDENTIFIER', 'CANCEL_IDENTIFIER']
            }]
        },
        notificationCallbackIOS: (message: any) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    };


    pushPlugin.register(iosSettings, (token: string) => {
        // update the token in the server
        alert("Device registered. Access token: " + token);
            });
        }
    }, (errorMessage: any) => {
        alert("Device NOT registered! " + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
    });
```

This is how i receive my token to the push notification, 
after a got the token when i'm using the pusher application everything works great, i'm getting the notification in the IOS device
but the problem is when im trying to send the notification from the server!.

I get this error :

> Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the
>   registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM.

Node code in my server

```
        var payload = {
        data: {
          targetId:userToken,
          body: "some text"
        }
      };
    var options = {
        priority: "high",
        contentAvailable: true,
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
      };
    Admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userToken, <any>payload,options)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('notification arrived successfully', response.results[0]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('notification failed', error);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

registration token for ios is not the same for android. I encountered the same wall you've encountered. You need to use `https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn` for IOS push notification. and `firebase` for android notification. You can do the logic on your backend by saving the token. with a field called `type` which is `ios or android` if ios you use `node-apn` and if android use `sendToDevice` provided by firebase.

Thats what i'm currently using with my current nativescript projects' I'm working on that involves push notification. Hope that helps you, mate.